# Backbone.js: form fields are not being sent in the request

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

Please forgive the newb question, but I am not finding answers elsewhere... probably because I'm not sure what the question should really be.

I am VERY new to Backbone.js, and I am trying to figure out why changes in the page's form fields are not being sent in POST/PUT requests. The 'change' event IS firing, and the View is catching it, but the model does not have the fields it should have from the form. I haven't been able to find anything that deals with this, so I am fairly certain we have just done something very wrong in our app... but I don't know how to figure out what that might be.

I realize this is not the most complete question, so please let me know if more info is required. I am so new to this that I am not even sure what one might need to track this down.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance,
vegtabill

Comment: can you the code of the view?  This may help with debugging the problem.

Comment: Hey there, and thanks for the reply. I think I have figured out what was missing from our code, thanks to Mr. Jimmy Miller's help. However, if I run into more trouble I will post what I have. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With backbone.js, there is more than one way to do something.  I personally update my model with the data from the view and then json serialize that data for transmission to the server side if I'm not using the REST capabilities build into backbone collections of models (i.e. the fetch, save, etc.)  You can use the [model.set()](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) method to do this.  I am fairly new to backbone too so please don't slam me if you take offense to my approach.  I know there are others out there that know a lot more about this topic than me.  This approach works for me and it enforces my personal goal of the model not having a reference to the view.  That separation is important to me personally.  To be more explicit, I listen for events on my view that I then use to update my model.

Comment: And on a side note I'm a big dead phan and general groovy music enthusiast, cheers!

Comment: I definitely am not in the business of slamming people... no worries there. We're using the View to update the Model as well, but the changed fields are not showing up. The only "field" that seems to be different in the debug output is a "1=1" addition. Is it possible that we are doing serialization incorrectly? Thanks again, very much.

Comment: If I understand correctly, and I might not, you're going to need to call model.set() in the change event handler to actually update the model.  Does that make sense?  If you're calling model.set() are your values that you set not persisting in the model?  Could their be model validation that could be rejecting the values in the set()?

Comment: Makes perfect sense... I thought we were doing that, but let me look at something... you may have just given me the clue I needed. I'll let you know momentarily...

Comment: No luck. I totally get what you're saying, but in the change handler there is no data to set. The actual field that triggered the event is not sending anything to the View, so I don't have anything to set. Does that make sense, or am I just completely lost here? (Not that those conditions are mutually exclusive or anything!)

Comment: I'm assuming your event handlers are defined in your view, right?  You're going to have to query those values out of your view using jQuery or your choice of DOM surf board.

Comment: OK, that helps... I think! I'm going to see what I can get to happen from here. Thanks again, man! Hey, if you're interested, Bob Weir and Ratdog are playing LIVE tonight for FREE.Check it out: http://tristudios.com/

Comment: Man we are kindred spirits.  I saw Bob and Ratdog with the Col. in college in a very small venue in Oxford, MS one night.  It was magic.  I've never been so close to such great musicians in my life.  Take care, friend.

Comment: Feel free to email me as well.  My address is in my profile.  I don't mind helping you get your bearings in the backbone.js world.

Comment: I shall, thanks. And dude, you put me on the right track. It appears we missed a huge step in setting all of this up (Node, Backbone, MongoDB with Mongoose, Express, Require, etc, etc, etc...) Thanks a ba-zillion!